# Get inserted and updated rows after using upsert Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, upsert

When I use upsert function, I want to get inserted and updated rows . What should I do ?

Any idea is very important to me. Thank a lot !

I am using MySQL.

Here is my example code :

```
Flight::upsert([
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
    ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['departure', 'destination'], ['price']);
```

I tried many ways , but not working at all.

```
$dtbClass->upsert($this->items->toArray(), ['JAN'], $this->headings);

// Get records after upsert
$result = $dtbClass->whereIn('JAN', $this->janList)->get();

$classIds = $result->pluck('id')->toArray();

// check any class was created
$checkCreatedClass = false;
$checkUpdatedClass = false;
foreach ($result as $class) {
    if ($checkCreatedClass && $checkUpdatedClass) {
       break;
    }
    if ($class->wasRecentlyCreated) {
       $checkCreatedClass = true;
    } elseif ($class->wasChanged()) {
       $checkUpdatedClass = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like Laravel cannot returns affected by `upsert()` method rows, but you can add some flag to your updated/inserted items. For example, `updated_at` column.
Something like this:

```
$updatedAt = Carbon::now();

Flight::upsert([
        ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99, 'updated_at' => $updatedAt],
        ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150, 'updated_at' => $updatedAt]
    ], ['departure', 'destination', 'updated_at'], ['price', 'updated_at']);

$affectedFlights = Flight::where('updated_at', $updatedAt)->get();
```

> Note: MySQL requires unique index on all columns used in second
> argument to uniquely identify record in your table. So you need to
> create a composite unique index which contains all columns
> ('departure', 'destination', 'updated_at' in my example).

It seems to me that this is not the only way to solve the problem and cited it just as one of the examples.
I hope I helped you or gave you the right idea.
Good luck.